# Most efficient way to compare two dates; one with time, one without

Tags: c#, datetime, webforms

I want to compare two dates; one taken from a `Date` column in SQL and the current `DateTime.Now`.  The former has no time portion (technically it does, but it's zeroed out) and of course the later will have the current time to the nearest millisecond.  Here is what I am doing now, and it seems inefficient:

```
DateTime compareDate = Convert.ToDateTime(string.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", DateTime.Now));
if (myObj.EndDate < compareDate)
{
    myObj.Status = "PAST";
}
else if (myObj.StartDate <= compareDate && myObj.EndDate >= compareDate)
{
    myObj.Status = "ACTIVE";
}
else
{
    myObj.Status = "PENDING";
}
```

Is there a better way to strip time off a DateTime variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of the DateTime structure, or just use [DateTime.Today](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today).

e.g.

```
DateTime compareDate = DateTime.Now.Date
```

or

```
DateTime compareDate = DateTime.Today
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the property "Date" on the the DateTime variable you want to strip the time from.

```
var pureDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```